# Javascript - need separate symbols

Tags: javascript

I need separate next string:

```
"func(ab)"
```

**To:**

```
["func", "(", "ab", ")"]
```

---

i.e. separate "(" and ")" symbols. Tell me best trick with *str.split*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to do it like that:

```
var result = "func(ab)".split(/\b/);
```

This works exactly as you mentioned, giving you `["func", "(", "ab", ")"]` as a result. Here is the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/PKntA/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you dont have the text TokenSeparator in your input:

```
var result = inpout.replace("(", "(TokenSeparator");
result = result.replace(")", "TokenSeparator)");
result = result.split("TokenSeparator");
```